# While para analisar retorno de Select

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

boa tarde!

Estou tendo meu primeiro contato com MySQL, antes trabalhava com Oracle, e me deparei com um problema que no Oracle, eu tinha a seguinte estrutura:

```
for a in (select id, nome, salario from usuario)
loop
/* 
  Meu código aqui. Realizar um novo select, insert, update e etc.
*/
end loop;
```

Com essa estrutura eu conseguia trabalhar linha a linha do retorno do select, mas no MySQL procurei e não encontrei nada parecido, me parece que ele nem implementa o comando for. Gostaria de saber se alguem já precisou de algo parecido e como foi que resolveu o problema, ou mesmo idéias para contornar o problema já facilitaria muito.

Obrigado

Comment: Veja: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html

Answer (score 3):

Para iterar sobre um resultado de um `SELECT` utilize um [`CURSOR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html). Aplicado no seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE id INT;
  DECLARE nome CHAR(16);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id, nome FROM usuario;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur;
  
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO id, nome;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    
    // Aqui seu código
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;
END;
```

> [`CURSORS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html)
>
> MySQL supports cursors inside stored programs. The syntax is as in embedded SQL. Cursors have these properties:
>
> Asensitive: The server may or may not make a copy of its result table
>
> Read only: Not updatable
>
> Nonscrollable: Can be traversed only in one direction and cannot skip rows
>
> Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and after variable and condition declarations.

Em tradução livre:

> O MySQL suporta cursores dentro de procedimentos armazenados. A sintaxe é como no SQL padrão. Cursores possuem essas propriedades:
>
> Asensitive: O servidor pode ou não pode fazer uma cópia dos resultados da tabela
>
> Read only: Não atualizável
>
> Nonscrollable: Pode ser percorrido em apenas uma direção e não pode pular linhas
>
> A declaração do cursor deve aparecer antes da declação do handler e depois das variáveis e declarações condicionais.